# В чем разница между HTTP и HTTPS?

Tags: http, ssh, ssl, https, key

У меня есть личный кабинет купленного мной VDS server и в нем есть Опции ключи SSH. Мне не понятно в том что что значить SSH и могу ли  на него установить SSL ключ. SSL подойдет на SSH?
Кстати мой личный кабинет как OPENSTACK

Comment: какая связь между заголовком про http и https и телом вопроса о ssh?

Answer (score -1):

Отвечу просто, с http у вас письма с сайта будут попадать в СПАМ, а с https не будут.
Ну и чисто эстетическое удовлетворение в адресной строке видеть замочек вместо красного текста - "Сайт незащищен"